# Misunderstanding in Yii model

Tags: php, model, yii, render

I have a problem that i can`t get throught.

I am trying to display information from relational table like this:

```
    $dataProvider = PartnerSite::model()->with('siteCommercials')->findAll("user_id=" . Yii::app()->user->id);

    $this->render('index', array(
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'allMoney' => 1
    ));
```

But in my view i am seeing that error:

```
Relation "siteCommercials" is not defined in active record class "PartnerSite".
```

But the fact is that my model have relation:

```
public function relations() {
    return array(
        'goesFromSites' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'GoesFromSite', 'site_id'),
        'user' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'User', 'user_id'),
        'siteCommercials' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'SiteCommercial', 'site_id'),
    );
}
```

So my question is. Is there is something wrong? I can't get it... In only one that model is a lot of problems... BeforeSave() doesn't work and relations work not well. User relation is working just fine.

Full listing of "model":

```
<?php
    abstract class BasePartnerSite extends GxActiveRecord {

   public $siteCommercials = "oke";

   public static function model($className=__CLASS__) {
    return parent::model($className);
   }

   public function tableName() {
    return '{{partner_site}}';
   }

   public static function label($n = 1) {
    return Yii::t('app', 'PartnerSite|PartnerSites', $n);
   }

   public static function representingColumn() {
    return 'site_name';
   }

   public function rules() {
    return array(
        array('site_name', 'required'),
        array('user_id', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
        array('site_name', 'length', 'max'=>255),
        array('id, site_name, user_id', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
    );
   }

   public function relations() {
    return array(
        'goesFromSites' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'GoesFromSite', 'site_id'),
        'user' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'User', 'user_id'),
        'siteCommercials' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'SiteCommercial', 'site_id'),
    );
   }

   public function pivotModels() {
    return array(
    );
   }

   public function attributeLabels() {
    return array(
        'id' => Yii::t('app', 'ID'),
        'site_name' => Yii::t('app', 'Site Name'),
        'user_id' => null,
        'goesFromSites' => null,
        'user' => null,
        'siteCommercials' => null,
    );
   }

   public function search() {
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;

    $criteria->compare('id', $this->id);
    $criteria->compare('site_name', $this->site_name, true);
    $criteria->compare('user_id', $this->user_id);

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria' => $criteria,
    ));
   }
```

}

Comment: Are you sure the name of the file and the name of the class match? This also differs for WAMP and XAMP. The second capital (camelcase) in PartnerSite may throw things off...

Comment: yes i am sure that file is named just like that. I think about that in first place, but renaming didn`t do anything...

Comment: is your PartnerSite class extends from BasePartnerSite class?

Comment: Perhaps you should define relation also in `SiteCommercial`?

Answer (score 0):

Your class is *BasePartnerSite*. In this class you define relation *siteCommercials*.

Your error message: **"Relation "siteCommercials" is not defined in active record class "PartnerSite".**

So then shouldn't your code be?

```
$dataProvider = BasePartnerSite::model()->with('siteCommercials')->findAll("user_id=" . Yii::app()->user->id);
```